# The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric

I am running into the issue where Robolectric is having trouble with my AndroidManifest.xml. My app runs fine, but Robolectric is failing all my tests, even `assertTrue(true)`. The error is:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file /[blah]/build/res/all/debug/layout/activity_main.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class fragment
```

caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

The problem is that I already have that line in my manifest. Below are some of the relevant files:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.bryansills.studywithfriends"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_action_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/study">

        <activity
            android:name="com.bryansills.studywithfriends.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_api_key_v2"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        classpath 'com.squareup.gradle:gradle-android-test-plugin:0.9.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-test'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.+'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
    testCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}
```

MainActivityTest.java:

```
package com.bryansills.studywithfriends;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.ActionProvider;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;
import com.bryansills.studywithfriends.MainActivity;
import dalvik.annotation.TestTargetClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowToast;
import org.robolectric.tester.android.view.TestMenuItem;
import com.bryansills.studywithfriends.RobolectricGradleTestRunner;

import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.CharSequence;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.System;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private MenuItem settingsMenuItem;
    private MenuItem helpMenuItem;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mainActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().visible().get();
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        settingsMenuItem = new TestMenuItem(R.id.settings);
        helpMenuItem = new TestMenuItem(R.id.help);
    }

    @Test
    public void testTrue() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testActivity() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(mainActivity != null);
    }

    @Test
    public void settingsMenuItemShouldStartSettingsActivity() throws Exception {
        mainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(settingsMenuItem);
        assertTrue(ShadowToast.getTextOfLatestToast().equals("Settings"));
    }

    @Test
    public void helpMenuItemShouldStartSettingsActivity() throws Exception {
        mainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(helpMenuItem);
        assertTrue(ShadowToast.getTextOfLatestToast().equals("Help"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case - do you see any warning that Robolectric can't find AndroidManifest? What is your project structure?

Comment: I don't. I just commented out all the methods in MainActivityTest.java except for testTrue() and it passed.

The GitHub repo for this project is right [here](https://github.com/bryansills/study-android) if you want to see my project structure.

Comment: I confirm that Robolectric can not inflate maps fragment. Let ask on the robolectric mail list

Answer (score 7):

**Note :** First be quiet sure to add the Api key in the manifest After creating it in [here](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

Remove the old style `permission` from the Manifest. Remove given permission if exists.

```
<permission android:name ="com.example.locations.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
```

Google Map V2 add new feature to manifest. Add given code to the manifest..

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />// if this integer  is not showing Add latest google play services
```

besides

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="ENTER_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE" />
```

Don't forget to enter **API key** in `manifest`.

Also remove this..

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed for me by upgrading from Robolectric 2.1 to 2.3-SNAPSHOT (I did not test 2.2). However, I did then encounter a different issue:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 2131361793.  You must have the following declaration within the  element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

It seems this is a [different bug](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/950), which I "fixed" by hardcoding the GMS version into my Manifest rather than referencing it. This is probably not a good idea, but until the bug is fixed, it works...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application>
    <meta-data 
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```